# I am deploying a MERN app on Heroku but it crashes every time

Tags: node.js, heroku, crash, mern

This is the error in the log. Please help!

I developed a MERN app. Now, I like to deploy it on the Heroku server but the deployment fails. I found below errors in the log. If you know how to resolve it, please help.

Thanks.

```
2022-08-25T13:03:18.960331+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: path is not defined
2022-08-25T13:03:18.960331+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:19:24)
2022-08-25T13:03:18.960333+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
2022-08-25T13:03:18.960333+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
2022-08-25T13:03:18.960334+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
2022-08-25T13:03:18.960334+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
2022-08-25T13:03:18.960334+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
2022-08-25T13:03:18.960335+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
2022-08-25T13:03:19.102536+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-08-25T13:03:19.221226+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-08-25T13:15:13.121856+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=khalil-linkedin.herokuapp.com request_id=cac25f53-a0cd-42c9-89ab-3530c219e561 fwd="175.139.204.77" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-25T13:15:14.629068+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=khalil-linkedin.herokuapp.com request_id=01382c95-6fc0-4a55-af67-0b3f6b91e3be fwd="175.139.204.77" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: That is only part of the error message. Please [edit] your question and add all contiguous error and warning output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.